# datetime-local in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, components

There is a component:

class DatetimeFilter extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.changeFromTimeTaskEducation = this.props.changeFromTimeTaskEducation;
    this.changeToTimeTaskEducation = this.props.changeToTimeTaskEducation;
}

changeFromTimeTaskEducation = (event) => {
    // change value in parent
};

changeToTimeTaskEducation = (event) => {
    // change value in parent
};

render() {
    return (
                    <input onChange={this.changeFromTimeTaskEducation} className="filter_datetime_second_value"
                           type="datetime-local" value={this.props.fromTimeTaskEducation}/>
                    <input onChange={this.changeToTimeTaskEducation} className="filter_datetime_second_value"
                           type="datetime-local" value={this.props.toTimeTaskEducation}/>
    );
}
```

}

export default DatetimeFilter;

When I try to change the value in the input, an exception appears:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

How can this be solved?

I tried setting defaultValue, but it only initializes once.

Comment: Also format your code please.

Answer (score 0):

if you think you must have a value, set it as defaultValue and onChange maintain state

```js
<input onChange={this.changeFromTimeTaskEducation} className="filter_datetime_second_value"
                           type="datetime-local" defaultValue={this.props.fromTimeTaskEducation}/>
                    <input onChange={this.changeToTimeTaskEducation} className="filter_datetime_second_value"
                           type="datetime-local" defaultValue={this.props.toTimeTaskEducation}/>
```

Comment: If componentDidUpdate changes the value, it won't change for defaultValue.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an OnChange function that calls the parent (prop) functions. You are overwriting the functions from the parents with your local function definitions.

Here is a proper way to do what you want:

```
class DatetimeFilter extends Component {

    localFromTimeTaskEducation = (event) => {
      this.props.changeFromTimeTaskEducation(event.target.value); //Or whatever value you are trying to pass
    }

    localToTimeTaskEducation = (event) => {
      this.props.changeToTimeTaskEducation(event.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <input 
            onChange={this.localFromTimeTaskEducation} 
            className="filter_datetime_second_value"
            type="datetime-local" 
            value={this.props.fromTimeTaskEducation}
          />

          <input 
            onChange={this.localFromTimeTaskEducation} 
            className="filter_datetime_second_value"
            type="datetime-local"
            value={this.props.toTimeTaskEducation}
          />
        );
    }
}
export default DatetimeFilter;
```

Comment: With value doesn't miss js